# How would we implement a monthly prize draw database?

Tags: civicontribute

Our charitable group runs a monthly prize draw. Volunteer collectors call on the members to collect the entry fee each month, but some people may not be at home so won't be entered. Some members pay for one month. Others pay for several months at a time. So entry in to each draw depends on whether a member is paid up that month. Each collector is assigned a set of members to call on.

Has anyone implemented something like this in CiviCRM?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the issue is partly about how you record fact that Mary made one payment which covered entry for April + May + June and therefore you need to ensure she is in the result for your search of folks who bought a ticket for each of those months.

I would suggest doing this as a Membership for a Monthly period, and therefore some who pays for 3 months gets 3 'cycles' of Membership and therefore will be returned as being 'in the draw' for each of those months.

Then do the rest per Jaap's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I have never implemented a draw but I assume that it is quite easy. You record a contribution and then you search for contacts who a have a paid contribution for that month.

Then you pick a random one. You could probably export the contacts then to excel and let excel pick a random row. 
Or you develop a custom search which picks a random contact out of the ones who have paid.